# Python: Read configuration file with multiple lines per key

Tags: python, configuration-files, text-parsing, sql

I am writing a small DB test suite, which reads configuration files with queries and expected results, e.g.:

```
query         = "SELECT * from cities WHERE name='Unknown';"
count         = 0
level         = 1
name          = "Check for cities whose name should be null"
suggested_fix = "UPDATE cities SET name=NULL WHERE name='Unknown';"
```

This works well; I divide each line using Python's `string.partition('=')`.

My problem is very long SQL queries. Currently, I just paste these queries as a one-liner, which is ugly and unmaintainable.

I want to find an elegant, Pythonic way to read the right of an expression, even if spans over many lines.

Notes:

- my SQL queries might contain the `=`
- I don't fancy the idea of forcing `"`s around the right hand side, because there are many existing files without it.

**EDIT:**

[ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) is great, but it forces me to add a space or tab at the beginning of every line in a multiline entry. This might be a great pain.

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: this space/tab is not included in the final value

Comment: Can you elaborate? Didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost exactly the use-case that made us switch to [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), [python implementation](http://pyyaml.org/), [documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation); you might want to look at [JSON](http://www.json.org/) as an alternative). YAML has some advantages over [`configparser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

- human readability (better than JSON for larger files);
- can serialize arbitrary python objects (which makes it as un-safe as `pickle`, but there is a `safe_load` function in the python implementation to alleviate this issue). This is already useful for something as simple as a `datetime` object.

For completeness sake, the main disadvantages (IMO):

- Python implementation by an order of magnitude slower than JSON implementation;
- less portable across platforms than JSON.

For example

```
import yaml

sql = """
query         : "SELECT * from cities
WHERE name='Unknown';"
count         : 0
level         : 1
name          : "Check for cities whose name should be null"
suggested_fix : "UPDATE cities SET name=NULL WHERE name='Unknown';"
"""

sql_dict = yaml.safe_load(sql)

print(sql_dict['query'])
```

prints

```
SELECT * from cities WHERE name='Unknown';
```

Answer (score 24):

The Python standard library module **[ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)** supports this by default. The configuration file has to be in a standard format:

```
[Long Section]
short: this is a normal line
long: this value continues
    in the next line
```

The configuration file above could be read with the following code:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('longsections.cfg')
long = config.get('Long Section', 'long')
```

Comment: I have a problem with this solution as errors are raised on parsing the file. According the documentation, for multiline values indentation is needed.

I added 4 spaces at the start of "in the next line" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would you suggest to use a regular expression... The code might look like this to give you are start:

```
import re

test="""query = "select * from cities;"
count = 0
multine_query = "select *
from cities
     where name='unknown';"
"""

re_config = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s*=\s*((?:".[^"]*")|(?:\d+))$', re.M)
for key, value in re_config.findall(test):
    if value.startswith('"'):
        value = value[1:-1]
    else:
        value = int(value)
    print key, '=', repr(value)
```

The output of this example is:

```
~> python test.py 
query = 'select * from cities;'
count = 0
multine_query = "select *\nfrom cities\n     where name='unknown';"
```

Hope that helps!

Regards,
Christoph

Comment: +1 That should work, but I really prefer a ready-made package that supports all kinds of edge conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Python 3.11+, [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) is the new hotness which is *included in the standard library*. It's like a simpler YAML which is much more focused on being an editable config format (many TOML libraries usually don't provide a way to write TOML).

```ini
# yourconfig.toml  (the filename assumed below, tho this is also a comment.)
query         = "SELECT * from cities WHERE name='Unknown';"
count         = 0
level         = 1   # 1 = foo, 2 = bar, 3 = baz  (other example comment)
name          = "Check for cities whose name should be null"
suggested_fix = """
UPDATE cities 
SET name=NULL 
WHERE name='Unknown';"""
```

The provided library is [`tomllib`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/tomllib.html), and you can use it like so:

```py
import tomllib

with open("yourconfig.toml") as f:
    conf = tomllib.load(f)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(conf)
# {'count': 0,
#  'level': 1,
#  'name': 'Check for cities whose name should be null',
#  'query': "SELECT * from cities WHERE name='Unknown';",
#  'suggested_fix': "UPDATE cities \nSET name=NULL \nWHERE name='Unknown';"}
```

Note that the `suggested_fix` key includes the newlines (`\n`) implied by the multiline string. You can use a trailing backslash to remove them, though if the value is SQL, they don't matter, so I wouldn't clutter it up.

Other benefits are that the `count` and `level` values are integers. TOML's built-in types include strings, arrays/lists, maps/dicts, ints, floats, datetimes, and booleans.

TOML has rigid types that aren't "cleverly" inferred.

- In YAML, `on` might be a boolean or a string, depending on if you're on version 1.1 or 1.2. In TOML it's a syntax error unless you quote it. If you wanted a boolean, use exactly one of `true` or `false`.
- In YAML, `O.1` is a string (it starts with an uppercase O), in TOML it's a syntax error.
- In YAML, you basically need https://yaml-multiline.info/ to figure out how to get your multiline string to be exactly what you expect, and even then it still takes me a while. [In TOML](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#string) it *can* kinda be the same as if you wrote it in Python (escaping rules are a bit different, using single/double quotes impacts it, and trailing backslashes trims whitespace)